# The "rate" in the Azure usage report is different from Ratecard API - MeterRates

Tags: azure, ratecard-api

I'm using the Pay-As-You-Go offer type (0003P) and found out the "rate" for some of the services are not the same with by using Ratecard API.

```
ex: the rate is "0.624988" for A0 VM (Windows) in JA East from usage report, but "0.7213" in MeterRate from Ratecard API. (Currency is TWD)
```

I followed the article: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt219004.aspx)

And here is my request example: [this one here](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/2984436c-xxxx-xxxx-805b-bc5d15be7ad8/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&$filter=OfferDurableId%20eq%20%27MS-AZR-0003p%27%20and%20Currency%20eq%20%27TWD%27%20and%20Locale%20eq%20%27zh-TW%27%20and%20RegionInfo%20eq%20%27TW%27)

Does anyone knows how to modify the request endpoint to get the same rate from Ratecard align with the usage report ?